# Issue with tkinter importing on PyCharm (Python 3.6.6)

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I'm trying to use tkinter for the first time in python 3.6.6, using PyCharm. After importing tkinter, I wasn't able to use the Tk() function to create a window, but instead got an inspection stating that "Tk()" is an unresolved reference. When I run my short program, it also gives me name error. Can someone please tell me what the issue could be?

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this code is ok.

Comment: run code without PyCharm to see if it works. Maybe problem is PyCharm, not Python.

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting when running in command line ```C:\Users\raymond.tran\PycharmProjects\Learning MatPlotLib>py tkinter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "C:\Users\raymond.tran\PycharmProjects\Learning MatPlotLib\tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Application(tk.Frame):
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Frame'```

Comment: you saved in file `tkinter.py` so now `from tkinter import *` imports from your file instead of module `tkinter`. Use different name - ie. `test_tkinter.py`

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Completely overlooked that.

Answer (score -2):

Try running the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the problem is that they named their file `tkinter.py`, so the import is picking up their file rather than the tkinter module. Changing the import syntax won't fix that problem.